# MongoDB query or aggregation to skip sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'd like to create a query or aggregation where the returned documents do not include sub-documents. I do not know that a given field will be a sub-document ahead of time (or I would just use the projection to skip them). So for example, if I have a document like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  field1: "a",
  field2: "b",
  field3: {
    subfield1: "c",
    subfield2: "d"
  }
}
```

When my query returns this document, it either skips field3, or replaces field3's value with something else (e.g. a string = "field_is_an_object").

As I said, I don't know ahead of time which fields will be sub-documents (or "object" types). The $redact operator was the closest I could find, but I couldn't figure out a syntax to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways you can achieve what you want:

The first one is pretty concise and requires just one aggregation stage which, however, is a little bit more complex and harder to understand:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $replaceRoot: { // create a new top level document
        "newRoot": { // ...which shall be
            $arrayToObject: { // ...created from an array
                $filter: { // ...that again should contain only those elements
                    input: { // ...from our input array
                        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" // ...which is our respective top level document transformed into an array of key-value pairs
                    },
                    cond: { // ...where
                        $ne: [ { $type: "$$this.v" }, "object" ] // ...the "v" (as in "value" field is not an object)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The second one I can think of is way more verbose but pretty easy to understand by adding the stages step-by-step (as always with the aggregation framework).

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "tmp": { // we create a temporary field
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" // that contains our respective root document represented as an array of key-value pairs
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$tmp" // flatten the temporary array into multiple documents
}, {
    $match: {
        "tmp.v": { $not: { $type: "object" } } // filter all documents out that we do not want in our result
    }
}, {
    $group: { // group all documents together again
        "_id": "$_id", // into one bucket per original document ("_id")
        "tmp": {
            $push: "$tmp" // and create an array with all the key-value pairs that have survived our $match stage
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { // create a new top level document...
        "newRoot": {
            $arrayToObject: "$tmp" // ...out of the data we have left in our array
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This worked...thank you. The detailed explanation is very helpful as well. My only comment is that the $objectToArray operation is new in 3.6, and 3.6 isn't officially released yet. I installed the latest RC of 3.6, and it did work.

Comment: It's available in 3.4: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I was at 3.4.0, so it didn't work for me; and I could have sworn I saw something that said "added in 3.6", so that's what I installed. Though the documentation clearly says it was added in 3.4.4. Thanks again.